# "Dominance" condition for consistency of MLE

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Consistency) for maximum likelihood estimation, there are a set of four conditions listed for the consistency of the maximum likelihood estimator.  I had a question about the last one, called "dominance" in that article:

> There exists $D(x)$ integrable with respect to the distribution $f(x | \theta_0)$ such that $$ {\big |}\ln f(x\mid \theta ){\big |}<D(x)\quad {\text{ for all }}\theta \in \Theta .$$

Does this mean that if the likelihood function goes to zero ($f(x|\theta) = 0$) anywhere on $\Theta$, this condition isn't valid since $|\ln (x|\theta)| \to \infty$ at such points?  Are there weaker conditions that would hold for a likelihood function which vanishes at some points in parameter space, but still lead to the MLE being consistent?

If a toy example would help, consider the likelihood function
$$
f(x | \theta) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2 \theta} \cos(x/\theta) & |x|\leq\pi\theta/2 \\
0 & |x|>\pi \theta/2 \end{cases} 
$$
with $\theta \in \Theta = [a,b]$ for some $a, b > 0$.
Would applying the MLE method to a sample drawn from this distribution lead, in the limit of a large number of data points, to an accurate estimate of $\theta$?